# Ruby - Compare 2 rows of result from a MySQL:Result object

Tags: mysql, ruby

I wish to look at the last 2 lines of a MySql:Result object in Ruby.

I need to ensure that one of the parameters in the 2 most recent lines are not the same.

```
time= @con.query('select victim, t, TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, t, now()) as timediff from iCu where userid = "'+user+'" and victim = "'+victim+'" order by t desc limit 2' )
```

This is my sql query. How can I compare the 2 values I get to ensure that the victim is not the same in these 2 lines? Either in the MySQL command or in ruby code after the call.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

edit: more info.

I'm using mysql gem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql2 gem, you can iterate the results to get the field you need:

```
results.each do |row|
  # conveniently, row is a hash
  # the keys are the fields, as you'd expect
  # the values are pre-built ruby primitives mapped from their corresponding field types in MySQL
  puts row["id"] # row["id"].class == Fixnum
  if row["dne"]  # non-existant hash entry is nil
    puts row["dne"]
  end
end
```

More Info [here](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#usage) for handling Mysql::Result

Answer (score 0):

`MySql:Result` include `Enumerable`, so you can use methods like `first`, `last`, `each` and so on on the instance of `MySql:Result` class.